# How to structure projects... Windows Service that starts a WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a WPF application that needs be spawned from a Windows Service (hopefully with some start up arguments from the service).  So right now all I have is the WPF project that we can assume is done.

Now I need to write the Windows Service. These two will always be deployed together, so I'd like them to be in the same project or installer project. Can you have a windows service and WPF side by side in one project? Not sure how VS would handle starting the project... Or would the Windows Service be a separate project, but part of the same installer project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Service will be a separate project in your solution. It can be a part of the Installer project, this will ensure that they are deployed together. All in all you will then have three projects in your solution.
1. WPF
2. Windows Service
3. Installer

You can add multiple executable and assemblies in your Installer project.

Answer (score 2):

Your windows Service and WPF app can be part of same 'project solution' in Visual Studio.  If you do not have Solution window open, click View > Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.  In Solution explorer window, the top root item shows the Solution name.

I think, you are yet to develop new Windows Service.  Right click Solution > Add New Project and create your new Windows service that goes with your WPF App.

In  your case, Windows service is the default 'Startup project'.  Right click your service project in Solution Explorer window  and set windows service as startup project

Deployment is based on your need.  Explore the Publish option in Project > Settings of your Windows service